# accessing html element from an iframe inside react component

Tags: reactjs, iframe, shopify

I have a component rendering an iframe received from an API endpoint. inside this iframe, there is a button where I want to add an `OnClick` listener and trigger an event. I can Access this button with Jquery in the browser console and do what I want, but not inside the react App. Is there a (smart) to access/reference this button and then add a listener to it ? for instance inside the `ComponentDidMount()` ? or an `addEventListener` this button inside the iframe ?

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
      window.addEventListener("click", this.handleFunction);
}

handleFunction = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    window.event = e // then get the clicked button from this event
}
```

but I do not know how to get to the button element that was pressed. It is somehow inside the event `e`